# What's the difference between these two solutions? Are both correct (task about modulus, extended euclidean algorithm)?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Find all solutions. You know that the multiplicative inverse is $2$.
>
> $$17x  \equiv 25 (\text{mod } 33)$$

**First way of solving it:**

Multiply this with $2$: $$34x \equiv 50(\text{mod } 33) $$

This is equivalent to:

$$1x \equiv 17 (\text{mod }33)$$

So solution is $x = 33k+17$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

**Second way of solving it:**

Multiply this with $2$: $$34x \equiv 50(\text{mod } 33) $$

$$50 \text { mod } 33= 17$$

Thus $x = 17$

---

My question, are both solutions correct? And if yes, which one would you recommend? The second seems more comfortable for sure.

Comment: The solutions are different, so how can they possibly both be correct? In particular, $x=17$ is just one solution, whereas you were asked to find *all* solutions. If there's more than one solution, your second answer must be wrong.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you now I understood, totally forgot the word "all" mentioned here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested solution might have been $$17x\equiv 25\pmod{33}$$

$$\iff 50x\equiv 25\pmod{33}$$

$$\stackrel{:25}\iff 2x\equiv 1\pmod{33}$$

(which we can do because $\gcd(25,33)=1$)

$$\iff x\equiv 2^{-1}\pmod{33}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$17x \equiv 25 \pmod{33}$$

The "natural" thing to do with $17x \equiv 25 \pmod{33}$ is to multiply both sides by what is $\dfrac{1}{17} \pmod{33}$. Since $2\cdot17 \equiv 34 \equiv 1 \pmod{33}$, then $\dfrac{1}{17} \equiv 2 \pmod{33}$. Multiply both sides by $2$ and you get

\begin{align}
   34x &\equiv 50 \pmod{33} \\
   x &\equiv 17 \pmod{33} \\
   x &= 17 + 33n \quad (n \in \mathbb Z)
\end{align}